# How to make snapshot of EBS Volume from aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I want to make snapshot of EBS Volume via script and it will be delete automatically after 1 day.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a snapshot with the [create-snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-snapshot.html) command:

```
aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id abcd1234
```

It is **not possible**, while *creating* a snapshot, to specify when to *delete* the snapshot.

However, you can use [Amazon EBS Snapshot Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html) to configure when snapshots should be deleted through a series of rules. The Snapshot Lifecycle can be configured via the AWS CLI, although it's easier to do via the console.

Comment: Actually I don't want to use Lifecycle there is are specific times but I want to delete this snapshot on my decided time.

Comment: In that case, you should use an Amazon CloudWatch Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function at the desired time, or at regular time intervals. You can then code the Lambda function to list the snapshots, check their age, then delete whichever you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I have fount this.

First, create an IAM user with these policies.

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then config awscli via **aws configure** command.

After this make .sh script for crontab.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# backup.py --volume-ids=vol-6b25bca2 --volume-ids=vol-6b25bca2 --expiry-days=1#
# 0 */3 * * * python3 /home/ubuntu/aws/snapshot_script.py --volume-ids=vol-010ce65755eb3f71e --expiry-days=1  
import argparse
import subprocess
import json
import logging
import time, datetime, dateutil.parser

profile = 'backup'       # Your AWS CLI profile
region = 'ap-southeast-1'  # replace this region to your EC2 instance region

def bash(command):
 process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 return process.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')

def getOurSnapshots():
 """
  Return a list of snapshot Dicts created with this plugin.
 """
 return json.loads(bash([
   "aws", "ec2", "describe-snapshots",
   "--filters", "Name=tag-key,Values=Group", "Name=tag-value,Values=backup",
   "--profile", profile,
   "--region", region,
   "--output=json"
  ]))['Snapshots']

def createSnapshots(volumeIds):
 """
  Return True if snapshots of the given volumes are created, else False

  Keyword arguments:
  volumeIds -- List of EBS volume IDs
 """
 # Create the snapshots
 snapshots = []
 for volumeId in volumeIds:
  snapshots.append(createSnapshotForVolume(volumeId))

 # Add Name and Group tags to the snapshot
 if len(snapshots):
  snapshotIds = []
  date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

  for snapshot in snapshots:
   snapshotIds.append(snapshot['SnapshotId'])

  # create-tags returns no output now so just perform the command and
  # return True
  bash([
   "aws", "ec2", "create-tags",
   "--resources", ' '.join(snapshotIds),
   "--tags", "Key=Name,Value='Snapshot "+date+"'", "Key=Group,Value=backup",
   "--profile", profile,
   "--region", region,
   "--output=json"
  ])

  return True

 return False

def createSnapshotForVolume(volumeId):
 """
  Return a Dict of a created snapshot for the given EBS volume

  Keyword arguments:
  volumeId -- An EBS volume ID
 """

 date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 message = "Creating snapshot for volume "+volumeId+"..."
 response = json.loads(bash([
  "aws", "ec2", "create-snapshot",
  "--volume-id", volumeId,
  "--description", "Volume Snapshot"+date,
  "--profile", profile,
  "--region", region,
  "--output=json"
 ]))
 message += response['SnapshotId']
 logging.info(message)

 return response

def deleteOldSnapshots(snapshots, max_age):
 """
  Delete all listed snapshots older than max_age
 """
 snapshotIds = []
 date = datetime.datetime.now()

 for snapshot in snapshots:
  snapshotDate = dateutil.parser.parse(snapshot['StartTime']).replace(tzinfo=None)
  dateDiff = date - snapshotDate

  if dateDiff.days >= max_age:
   message = "Deleting snapshot "+snapshot['SnapshotId']+" ("+str(dateDiff.days)+" days old)..."
   # delete-snapshot no longer returns any output
   bash([
    "aws", "ec2", "delete-snapshot",
    "--snapshot-id", snapshot['SnapshotId'],
    "--profile", profile,
    "--region", region,
    "--output=json"
   ])

   message += "done"
   logging.info(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='ADD YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE')
 parser.add_argument('-i','--volume-ids', help='EBS volume ID', required=True)
 parser.add_argument('-d','--delete-old', help='Delete old snapshots?', required=False, type=bool,default=True)
 parser.add_argument('-x','--expiry-days', help='Number of days to keep snapshots', required=False, type=int, default=7)
 args = parser.parse_args()

 logging.basicConfig(filename='backup.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S%p')

 # Get all active volumes
 volumeIds = args.volume_ids.split(',')
 # Create the snapshots
 if len(volumeIds):
  snapshots = createSnapshots(volumeIds)
  pass

 # Delete snapshots older than expiry-days
 if args.delete_old:
  deleteOldSnapshots(getOurSnapshots(), args.expiry_days)
```

Finally, add a crontab according to your volume name, making snapshot time and delete snapshot time.

```
0 */3 * * * python3 /home/ubuntu/aws/snapshot_script.py --volume-ids=vol-01fc7eeece0c20d97 --expiry-days=1
```